# Windows Environment Variable not working if different drive

Tags: windows, environment-variables

I could be over-simplifying the cause but I'm trying to set up `mongo` and `mongod` to run via their single word command.

I have made 2 Environment Variables.
`mongo:"C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4\bin\mongo.exe"`

and

`mongod:"C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4\bin\mongod.exe"`

However, when I try to run either command from anywhere besides `C:\Program Files` it just says `mongod is not a recognized command` etc etc.

Am I missing something special about how EnvVars work with Windows?

I was thinking it might be drive related since my projects are on D: but that didn't make sense as if I run the command `"C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4\bin\mongod.exe"` it'll work without issue.

Comment: What does any of this have to do with environment variables? I'm confused.

Comment: @melpomene I'm not sure I follow - Within Windows isn't it an Environment Variable to have a short cut to run an application?

Comment: No, not at all. Where did you get that idea?

Comment: @melpomene By the fact you assign them within "Environment Variables" section of the System?

Comment: How does that relate to shortcuts for applications?

Answer (score 1):

Don't create monogo and mongod variables.
Just append the *"C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4\bin\mongo.exe"* and *"C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4\bin\mongod.exe"* in 'path' variable of your environment variables.